# Proof of Interceting Lines

Tags: functions, continuity, proof-writing

I have this practice problem from a final exam study guide.

Let $f,g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)>g(a)$ but $g(b)>f(b)$. Prove that $\exists c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$.

My initial thought is to subtract the two functions and show that at some point c their difference is zero, but I don't quite know how to do so. My other was to form line segments from the endpoints, and show that when the two lines are substituted in for each other, you get a point in the domain. But I think this only works for linear functions, and not, say quadratics (IE the intersection point would be different)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Follow your initial thought. Remember the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Oh! So would I show that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ is within the region $[g(a),g(b)]$, pick any $x$ which results inbetween $[g(a),g(b)]$, and by IVT there is a $c$, which is equal to $f(c)$, and $g(c)$?

Comment: No -- still subtract the two functions _first_, like you were on your way to do.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll take a crack at it that way! Thanks!

Comment: @HenningMakholm , Is my answer below what you had in mind for me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some guidance, I think I might have the answer to this:

Let $f,g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)>g(a)$ but $g(b)>f(b)$. Prove that $\exists c \in[a,b]:f(c)=g(c)$.

Proof:

Define $h(x)$ as follows: $$h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$$Since $h(x)$ is a composition of two continuous functions, it shows that $h(x)$ is also continuous. Also, since $f(a)>g(a)$ and since $g(b)>f(b)$ then it shows that $$g(b)-f(b)>0\space and \space g(a)-f(a)<0$$$$\implies h(b)>0 \space and \space h(a)<0$$ By the IVT, $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $h(c) = 0$. Since $h(c) = 0$,$$h(c) = g(c)-f(c) = 0$$$$\implies g(c) = f(c) $$
Is this a sound proof?

Comment: Yes, this works -- although you should probably state explicitly that your $h$ is necessarily continuous. (And it is generally bad style to use "such that" or "s.t." together with "$\exists$". Either keep things symbolic, in which case the syntax is just $\exists c\in [a,b]:f(c)=g(c)$, or use English words: "There is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$")

Comment: Fixed! And thank you for the nudge! I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: A small comment: Normally, composition means $h(x) = f(g(x))$, and not $h(x) =g(x) - f(x)$, which is subtraction.

Comment: @Hetebrij Oh! Indeed it does. Should I change composition to combination?